# SQL Server Alerts on VMs

Tags: sql-server, alerts

Newbie here..

Hello
Searching online and I could not find any articles/blogs that pointed, related or had any opinions regarding SQL Server and SQL Server Alerts installed/running on virtual machines. Question is, how important, or relevant are SQL Server Alerts (19-25,823,824, or 825) if the environment SQL is installed on is running as a guest on a a VM? Are there other solutions.

Regards,

Comment: I don't understand why you think hardware failures might be less important on a VM. The disks can still go bad, and you probably want to know about it. I'd prefer multiple alerts to 0.

Comment: I agree. However, if alerts are configured on a VM running SQL, if the Host's hardware begins to fail would said alerts capture those faults? My concern are SQL alerts configured on the VM would not capture faults on Host hardware but only capture faults on the virtual hardware. Or am I wrong?

Comment: nowhere did I say you should have alerts on the VM but ***NOT*** on the host.

Comment: we decided to go with Nagios monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that they are equally important on physical or VMs.

suggest you to create all [critical alerts](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/how-to-create-sql-server-agent-alerts-for-critical-errors/) as highlighted by Glenn Berry.

Comment: thanks.. but we decided to go with Nagios

Comment: Nagios is a monitoring/alerting software. I highly recommend to create **SQL Server alerts** (as I highlighted above)- as they are tightly integrated with SQL OS.

Comment: Agreed, but if SQL is installed on a guest VM, will SQL alerts recognize if the HOST hardware begins to report errors?

Comment: If the host hardware begins to report errors, then SQL server running on the VM will report errors as the VM will be affected. Prevention is better than cure and hence my recommendation. Also, even if HOST is fine, but the disks on VM becomes corrupted, then these alerts will be life saving for you.